# Table icl_string_pages decrease performance of site

Tags: database, wordpress

Good morning

I have a big problem with the performance of one site web in Wordpress.

I saw, the error is in the table **icl_string_pages** he has 32,487,013 rows and the size is over 1GB.

How do I clean the table?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [WPML.org site](https://wpml.org/errata/big-icl_string_pages-table-wpml-3-5-0-causes-performance-issues/) this happens when you have many variables on your URLs.

The currently offered workaround given:

> ## Workaround
>
> The current workaround is to upgrade to WPML Multilingual CMS 3.5.1
> beta 3 or to wait for the official release of WPML Multilingual CMS
> 3.5.1
>
> Updating from a previous beta (3.5.1 beta 2 or 3.5.1 beta 1) requires
> that you set temporary this setting in your wp-config.php
>
> `1 define('ICL_SITEPRESS_DEV_VERSION', '3.5.1');`
>
> Then after visiting your site once, you have to remove that setting.

This workaround is supposed to both prevent this problem from continuing and clean up (truncate) the bloated table.

Comment: Thanks @hexblot for your answer, I will try with this steps and return with the verdict.

Comment: I made the steps, and I think this works. But How I know if the version of WPML Multilingual is now 3.5.1?